# htaccess https redirect not using my latest css file? – http and https version of the site use different css

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I noticed that when I add the https redirect it doesn't load my most recent css changes. It used to work before but I'm not sure why it doesn't know.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

The site still loads the rest of the css but not the latest one where I linked a background image on 'images.css'. What is the cause of this? I've tried adding `<base href="/" />` below the `<head>` on each of my pages but it doesn't seem to work

Why does this happen and any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that this was a cloudflare issue and to solve it you need to purge their cache. I don't know why this got downvoted and I hope someone who encounters the same problem sees this as it might be confusing for them as well.